# Monitor connected to VGA1 went blank!

Tags: grub2, display, resolution, external-monitor, 14.10

I have been able to work for the last 3 weeks on two monitors on a Xubuntu 14.04.01 without a problem. All the monitors have been detected nicely and everything run smoothly. One of the monitors is connected to VGA1 and the other is connected to DVI1 Nice!

However, the monitor which is connected to VGA1 has decided to go blank which means that the monitor even though it shows that has got the power and display something, it returns a black screen. If I run xrandar I can detect the monitor. I can detect the monitor with the 'display' GUI and therefore no problem there either..

Here are some results...

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0 +
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 359mm x 287mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
TV1 unknown connection (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   848x480        59.9 +
   640x480        59.9 +
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And

```
xrandr|grep 'VGA1'
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
```

Here are some other details:

```
 $ uname -a
Linux kos-TravelMate 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 18:00:35 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux



   ~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 04)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 04)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev d4)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
00:1e.3 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) SATA Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB21 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
05:01.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 005e
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
05:02.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WM3B2300BG Mini-PCI Card
    Kernel driver in use: ipw2200
05:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB-712/4 Cardbus Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
05:04.1 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
05:04.2 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
05:04.3 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc: (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
05:04.4 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 007a
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
```

I have used intel installer and have been able to update all of my drivers.

**Update 1:** It's alive!..The monitor was turned on for a couple of seconds after upgrading to Unicorn. Surely, there must be something wrong somewhere... Can anyone think of how to find out where and what to do please?

**Update 2**. I was playing around with the `/etc/default/grub` file where I have done all the possible combinations on `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` but without any success. 
The monitor's still sleeping. 
I can see that is trying to give something back but the indicator stays  orange colour similar to when it is idle and the screen remains blank. I have seen it working only for 2 seconds at some point and that's it. 
I have  connected the VGA1 to another monitor where  and the output that the other monitor gave was 'signal input is out of range'. I have plugged in the Monitor a Lubuntu 14.04 machine and it worked nicely.  I do not know what else to do???

**update 3** I have tried to boot from a Live CD 12.04 and the result was the same the VGA1 is still blank.

Here is some results from log. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8691151/

I am on Acer Travemate and I have jumped in to xubuntu 14.10. I was hoping that Unicorn would have fixed the issue but I do not see that happening.

Is this because my graphics cars has been corrupted? How somebody can check that?
Any help please?

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller
           Display Server: X.Org 1.16.0 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.0hz, 1280x1024@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 915GM x86/MMX/SSE2
           GLX Version: 1.4 Mesa 10.3.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried updating the drivers? Assuming you are on a 64-but Ubuntu, install https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb Once that is installed, there should be a new program installed called the Intel Linux Graphics Installer. Run it, follow the instructions, reboot, and see if your monitor works now.

Comment: I totally forgot to tell you. Before running the installer but after installing the package, copy and paste this large command and run it: wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

Comment: @fuzzyToothpaste Here is the result of the first

Comment: @fuzzyToothpaste I run the first command.. But how you get to run the installer? I have got the deb file downloaded,  Tried to run it but somehow it returns - wrong architecture 'amd64';

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste here is the full message: dpkg: error processing archive intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste I have upgraded the drivers as suggested but I have got two ne issues. DVI1's flickering when I point with the mouse and mouse is distorted like a long dashed line. What do I do from here now? any suggestions?